error "assignment might update an object not in the enclosing context's modifies clause"
I have to create a class that contains an anonymous constructor, a named constructor CreatePrimeBuffer(primes: seq〈nat〉) that creates a PrimeBuffer object, and a method CheckPrime(n: nat) returns (p: bool) checks whether n is prime. It checks the database and uses that result if it is in the database. If the number is not in the database, it calculates whether the number is prime (using the method IsPrime below), adds the number to the database if it is prime and returns the result. So far I have come with this:
class PrimeBuffer{
    var s: set<nat>
constructor()
ensures |s|==0
{
    s:={};
}
method CheckPrime(n: nat) returns (p: bool)
modifies s
{
    if n in s {p:=true;}
    else {p:= IsPrime(n);
        if p==true {s:=s+{n};}
    }
    
}
constructor CreatePrimeBuffer(primes: seq<nat>)//no funcional
//ensures |primes| == |s|
//ensures forall i | 0<=i< |primes| :: primes[i] in s
{
   s := set x:nat | x in primes :: x;
    //assert |primes| == |s|;
    // var i:=0;
    // while i< |primes|

    // {
    //     s:=s+{primes[i]};
    //     i:=i+1;
    // }
}
}
ghost predicate prime (n: nat)
{n>1 && ( forall d | 1 < d < n :: n % d != 0) }

method IsPrime ( n: nat ) returns ( p: bool )

{
    p:=true;
    var i:=0;
    while i< (n/2)
    {
        if i%n != 0 {p:=false;}
        i:=i+1;
    }
}


But the method CheckPrime prints an error on "s:=s+{n};" How can I add a nat to my set of nats?
I tried different things, but they all come to the same problem.

What you really want is not
modifies s
but
modifies this or modifies this`s
Modifies talks about which memory locations, and the only memory locations you can specify in Dafny is a whole reference object (all its fields), like in the first modifies, or a single field, like in the second example.
